# Security Risks Of Letting Users Send Pings On System

Tags: ping, cmd

Through a chatbot I am developing, users will have the ability to ping servers. The command is `.ping <IP/Domain> <other criteria>` and this will be passed to python which will use `subprocess.run(f'ping <aforementioned ip and criteria>')`.

This will then return the result over Teams.

What security measures or message filtering should I implement to ensure the safety of my program and company server?

Comment: And what prevents me from sending “127.1;cat /etc/passed” for example?

Comment: `ping` is not the problem here, it's passing user-supplied strings to a pything `run` process.